# Extracting data from a table using Python Beautiful soup

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to parse rows within a table (the departure board times) from the following:

```
buscms_widget_departureboard_ui_displayStop_Callback("
 <div class='\"livetimes\"'>
 <table class='\"busexpress-clientwidgets-departures-departureboard\"'>
  <thead>
   <tr class='\"rowStopName\"'>
    <th colspan='\"3\"' data-bearing='\"SW\"' data-lat='\"51.7505683898926\"' data-lng='\"-1.225102186203\"' title='\"oxfajmwg\"'>
     Divinity Road
    </th>
    <tr>
     <tr class='\"textHeader\"'>
      <th colspan='\"3\"'>
       text 69325694 to 84637 for live times
      </th>
      <tr>
       <tr class='\"rowHeaders\"'>
        <th>
         service
        </th>
        <th>
         destination
        </th>
        <th>
         time
        </th>
        <tr>
        </tr>
       </tr>
      </tr>
     </tr>
    </tr>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   <tr class='\"rowServiceDeparture\"'>
    <td class='\"colServiceName\"'>
     4A  (OBC)
    </td>
    <td class='\"colDestination\"' rise\"="" title='\"Elms'>
     Elms Rise
    </td>
    <td 21:49:00\"="" class='\"colDepartureTime\"' data-departuretime='\"20/02/2017' mins\"="" title='\"5'>
     5 mins
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr class='\"rowServiceDeparture\"'>
    <td class='\"colServiceName\"'>
     4A  (OBC)
    </td>
    <td class='\"colDestination\"' rise\"="" title='\"Elms'>
     Elms Rise
    </td>
    <td 22:11:00\"="" class='\"colDepartureTime\"' data-departuretime='\"20/02/2017' mins\"="" title='\"27'>
     27 mins
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr class='\"rowServiceDeparture\"'>
    <td class='\"colServiceName\"'>
     4  (OBC)
    </td>
    <td class='\"colDestination\"' title='\"Abingdon\"'>
     Abingdon
    </td>
    <td 22:29:00\"="" class='\"colDepartureTime\"' data-departuretime='\"20/02/2017' title='\"22:29\"'>
     22:29
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr class='\"rowServiceDeparture\"'>
    <td class='\"colServiceName\"'>
     4A  (OBC)
    </td>
    <td class='\"colDestination\"' rise\"="" title='\"Elms'>
     Elms Rise
    </td>
    <td 22:49:00\"="" class='\"colDepartureTime\"' data-departuretime='\"20/02/2017' mins\"="" title='\"65'>
     65 mins
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr class='\"rowServiceDeparture\"'>
    <td class='\"colServiceName\"'>
     4A  (OBC)
    </td>
    <td class='\"colDestination\"' rise\"="" title='\"Elms'>
     Elms Rise
    </td>
    <td 23:09:00\"="" class='\"colDepartureTime\"' data-departuretime='\"20/02/2017' title='\"23:09\"'>
     23:09
    </td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
<div class='\"scrollmessage_container\"'>
 <div class='\"scrollmessage\"'>
 </div>
</div>
<div class='\"services\"'>
 <a class='\"service' href='\"#\"' onclick="\&quot;serviceNameClick('');\&quot;" selected\"="">
  all
 </a>
 <a class='\"service\"' href='\"#\"' onclick="\&quot;serviceNameClick('4');\&quot;">
  4
 </a>
</div>
<div class="dptime">
 <span>
  times generated at:
 </span>
 <span>
  21:43
 </span>
</div>
");
```

In particular, I'm trying to extract all the departure times - so I'd like to capture the minutes from departure - for example 12 minutes away.

I have the following code:

```
# import libraries
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# specify the url
quote_page = 'http://www.buscms.com/api/REST/html/departureboard.aspx?callback=buscms_widget_departureboard_ui_displayStop_Callback&clientid=Nimbus&stopcode=69325694&format=jsonp&servicenamefilder=&cachebust=123&sourcetype=siri&requestor=Netescape&includeTimestamp=true&_=1487625719723'

# query the website and return the html to the variable 'page'
page = urllib.request.urlopen(quote_page) 

# parse the html using beautiful soap and store in variable `soup`
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')  

print(soup.prettify())
```

I'm not sure how to find the minutes from departure from the above? Is it something like:

```
minutes_from_depart = soup.find("tbody", attrs={'td': 'mins'})
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you try this ?

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

quote_page = 'http://www.buscms.com/api/REST/html/departureboard.aspx?callback=buscms_widget_departureboard_ui_displayStop_Callback&clientid=Nimbus&stopcode=69325694&format=jsonp&servicenamefilder=&cachebust=123&sourcetype=siri&requestor=Netescape&includeTimestamp=true&_=1487625719723'

page = urllib.request.urlopen(quote_page).read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')  

print(soup.prettify())

minutes = soup.find_all("td", class_=re.compile(r"colDepartureTime"))

for elements in minutes:
    print(elements.getText())
```

Comment: When I ran this I received the following error message `bs4.FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: lxml. Do you need to install a parser library?` - I assume I'm missing a library

Comment: @AnthonyW You can try with "html.parser" instead of "lxml", i don't think it makes difference in this case

Comment: yes, thanks. I ran your suggestion and worked. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

So I got to my answer with the following code - which was actually quite easy once I had played around with the `soup.find_all` function:

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# specify the url
quote_page = 'http://www.buscms.com/api/REST/html/departureboard.aspx?callback=buscms_widget_departureboard_ui_displayStop_Callback&clientid=Nimbus&stopcode=69325694&format=jsonp&servicenamefilder=&cachebust=123&sourcetype=siri&requestor=Netescape&includeTimestamp=true&_=1487625719723'

# query the website and return the html to the variable 'page'
page = urllib.request.urlopen(quote_page) 

# parse the html using beautiful soap and store in variable `soup`
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')  

for link in soup.find_all('td',class_='\\"colDepartureTime\\"'):
    print(link.get_text())
```

I get the following output:

```
10:40
10 mins
21 mins
30 mins
40 mins
50 mins
60 mins
```